# module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to use the Thin plate shape transformer function.

```
tps = cv2.createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer()
```

However, this error is shown:

> module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer'.

I have installed `contrib` using:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

but the problem is still unsolved. I use `opencv 4.5.4` and `python 3.8.5`

Comment: Can you access other opencv functions with cv2. prefix?

Comment: @Micka I can use other opencv function for example cv2.imread

Answer (score 1):

See this issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/177

It appears that that method has been moved out of the base package. So, you need to install OpenCV with `contrib` modules. For details, please open the link above.

Comment: Thank you @Green  I go through that link and I have installed opencv-contrib-python but the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: @deema , you must uninstall the old opencv

Comment: thank you @berak its work after I uninstall the old version.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem using the following commands.

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python
```